# How to get the time difference between two times (24h format)

Tags: c

I am currently trying to create a program where the user gives two values (times, hh:mm:ss) and gets the difference between the two times. This works, if one would only use 12h formats; however, using the 24h format is a must.

My current time struct looks like the following:

```
typedef struct time {
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
} time;
```

And my current function to calculate the difference looks like this:

```
time calculateTimeDiff(time time1, time time2) {
    time timeResult;

    timeResult.hours = time1.hours - time2.hours;

    if(time1.minutes != 00 && time2.minutes != 00) {
            timeResult.minutes = time1.minutes - time2.minutes;
    }
    else {
            timeResult.minutes = 00;
    }

    if(time1.seconds != 00 && time2.seconds != 00) {
            timeResult.seconds = time1.seconds - time2.seconds;
    }
    else {
            timeResult.seconds = 00;
    }

    while(timeResult.seconds > 60) {
        timeResult.seconds -= 60;
        timeResult.minutes += 1;
    }

    while(timeResult.minutes > 60) {
        timeResult.minutes -= 60;
        timeResult.hours += 1;
    }

    return timeResult;
}
```

My attempts to support the 24h format have been to add 12 hours to the time if the hours "exceed" the 12 hour format, and to divide the time by two (haven't been far from complete shots in the dark, just to see what works and what wouldn't work). However, this has only resulted in getting incorrect results.

Any and all answers appreciated!

Comment: Look at this function: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_difftime.htm

Comment: `if(time1.minutes != 00 && time2.minutes != 00)` What is this check for?

Comment: "*My attempts to fix the issue*" - Fix what issue? What's the problem?

Comment: @YaatSuka Will do!

Comment: How does this code not support the 24h format?

Comment: @melpomene The check was partly for debugging purposes and might not be needed anymore .However, at the time, it did weird things when it tried to subtract 00 from 00. As for the issue i've edited the question, but currently it doesn't exactly work like it should if you enter any times exceeding the 12-hour format.

Comment: "doesn't exactly work like it should" is not a problem description. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Subtracting 0 from 0 doesn't do weird things, it just gives you 0.

Comment: @melpomene It did when I tried it, and I'm just as confused as you are. But like i said, it might have been "accidentally" fixed since then, will have to try. That being said, I just tested the program once again, and if we assume time1 is 22:00:00 and time2 is 08:00:00, it gives a difference of 14 hours.

Comment: @Xariez ... what's wrong with 14 hours?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155727/discussion-between-xariez-and-melpomene).

Comment: Use std library functions `difftime` `mktime` etc instead.  Your time function can't wrap past midnight.

Comment: try using `time.h` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get the time difference between two times (24h format)

Although code could use many if-then-else's as in OP's code, it would be simple to convert the h:m:s time into seconds, subtract, and convert back to h:m:s.  So I recommend a re-write:

```
typedef struct time {
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
} time;

long time_sec(time t) {
  return (t.hours * 60L + t.minutes)*60 + t.seconds;
}

time sec_time(long s) {
  time t;
  t.hours = s / 3600;
  s %= 3600;
  t.minutes = s / 60;
  t.seconds = s %= 60;
  return t;
}

time calculateTimeDiff(time time1, time time2) {
  long t1 = time_sec(time1);
  long t2 = time_sec(time2);
  long diff = t1 - t2;
  return sec_time(diff);
}

#include <stdio.h>
void test(time t1, time t2) {
  printf("t1: %3d:%3d:%3d,    ", t1.hours, t1. minutes, t1.seconds);
  printf("t2: %3d:%3d:%3d,    ", t2.hours, t2. minutes, t2.seconds);
  time t3 = calculateTimeDiff(t1, t2);
  printf("t1-t2: %3d:%3d:%3d,   ", t3.hours, t3. minutes, t3.seconds);
  t3 = calculateTimeDiff(t2, t1);
  printf("t2-t1: %3d:%3d:%3d\n", t3.hours, t3. minutes, t3.seconds);
}

int main(void) {
  test((time){14,00,00}, (time){13,00,00});
  test((time){22,00,00}, (time){04,00,00});
}
```

Output

```
t1:  14:  0:  0,    t2:  13:  0:  0,    t1-t2:   1:  0:  0,   t2-t1:  -1:  0:  0
t1:  22:  0:  0,    t2:   4:  0:  0,    t1-t2:  18:  0:  0,   t2-t1: -18:  0:  0
```

Note that the difference may result in negative values for the members of `time` returned in `calculateTimeDiff()`.

Comment: Shows your brain is wired correctly (`simply` -> `simple`) (which the human brain interprets phonetically when typing as `simpl - e` and `y` makes the `e` sound at the end...`:)`

Comment: I agree with the general approach.  The OP needs to consider the correct course of action for differences that overflow the 24 hour mark, and how to handle negative times.  There's no simple answer; it depends on what is appropriate in the context where the results will be used.

Comment: I tried to have a look at this, compare and implement it in my own code. However, it seems to return a 59 minute difference between 14:00:00 and 13:00:00. Furthermore, it gives incorrect values if we do 22:00:00 and 04:00:00 for example. That being said though, this code IS a lot cleaner than mine, so thank you for it!

Comment: @Xariez An off-by-1 with "14:00:00 and 13:00:00" is likely due to the original h:m:s value being different (off-by-1) than expected. "it gives incorrect values if we do 22:00:00 and 04:00:00 for example." would be more useful if the comment include the "incorrect values" and the expected vales.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to time structure instead of both start and end time integer value

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void difftime(int startTime, int iRecordEndTime)
{
    int duration_min = 0;
    cout<<"iRecordEndTime = "<<iRecordEndTime<<endl;
    cout<<"startTime      = "<<startTime<<endl;
    if ( (iRecordEndTime/100 < startTime/100) || ((iRecordEndTime/100 == startTime/100) && (iRecordEndTime%100 <= startTime%100)) )
    {
        duration_min = ((iRecordEndTime / 100 + 24)*60 + iRecordEndTime%100) - ((startTime/100)*60 + startTime%100);
    }
    else
    {
        duration_min = (iRecordEndTime / 100 - startTime/100)*60 + (iRecordEndTime%100 - startTime%100);
    }
    cout<<"duration_min = "<<duration_min<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"enter the start time Hour:Minutes xxxx"<<endl;
    int startTime{0};
    cin>>startTime;
    cout<<"enter the End time Hour:Minutes xxxx"<<endl;
    int iRecordEndTime{0};
    cin>>iRecordEndTime;
    difftime(startTime, iRecordEndTime );
}

Output
    enter the start time Hour:Minutes xxxx\
    2300\
    enter the End time Hour:Minutes xxxx\
    0000\
    iRecordEndTime = 0\
    startTime      = 2300\
    duration_min = 60
```